# free shipping based on subtotal excluding tax

Tags: free-shipping

how can i tell to calculate free shipping off the subtotal without tax?
`getBaseSubtotal` does not seem to work?

```
   if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal') || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '188.94.20.43')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount()` worked!